# Can't port forward on port 25565 or any other port

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding, iptables

### The Problem:

I'm unable to port forward port **WAN port [25565]** to server **[IP: 192.168.8.100:25565]**

---

### Network Info:

- IP| **Dynamic**
- Router WAN IP| **10.204.250.128**
- External IP| **115.164.xx.xx**
- Server IP(LAN)| **192.168.8.100**
- Server Port(LAN)| **25565**
- Default Gateway| **192.168.8.1**
- Network Mask| **255.255.255.0**
- Broadcast IP(LAN)| **192.168.8.255**
- Network Interface| **enp3s0**
- IPTABLES Default Policy| **ACCEPT**
  **Additional Info:**
- ISP| **Digi**
- Internet Plan| **Mobile broadband**
- Router| **Huawei b310s-518**

---

### Port Forwarding:

My router is configured to forward **[WAN Port:*25565*] to [SERVER IP(LAN):*192.168.8.100:25565*]**:

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoOne.jpg)

---

### IPTABLES configuration:

Only **FILTER** and **NAT** tables are uniquely configured others are left to default policy(accept):

- **FILTER table:**
  [FILTER TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqitW.jpg)
- **NAT table:**
  [NAT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6qP8.jpg)

---

### Solutions i've tried

- **Listening on port 25565:**
  [LISTEN PORT 25565](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD4IH.jpg)
- **Disabling IPTABLES entirely**

---

### Footnotes:

I'm conflicted whether static ip is required for port forwarding and i've yet to try port forwarding using static ip.

Comment: Given that your WAN IP is in the 10.0.0.0/8 network, I assume you do not have a public facing IP address. You have properly forwarded the port on your end, it's just that your ISP is also doing things and probably using your external address for multiple costumers. Either host your server on a rented server, those usually come with public and unfiltered IP addresses and Internet connections, or get a public facing and routed IP address from your ISP.

Comment: i've always had some suspicion that my isp is responsilbe for this problem, thanks for clarifying the problem